# Get pages by template name - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a Wordpress theme and I've been trying all day to get a list of pages in which I've asigned a template.

I made this file called page-gallery.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Gallery
 */
get_header(); 
?>
<h1>Gallery</h1>
<?php
get_footer();
```

And now in the admin panel I can see in the Template drop box the Gallery option, I've assigned it to three pages... but now, I'm trying to use:

```
$pages = get_pages([
                'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'meta_value' => 'page-gallery.php',
            ]);
```

And it returns NULL! I've searched all around the internet and I have tried everything but I don't know what's causing the problem :/

Comment: If you check the database, are you sure the *exact* `meta_value` is page-gallery.php and not something like templates/page-gallery.php?

Comment: Now that I check, I can't actually se any key with _wp_page_template

Comment: `_wp_page_template` is in the `wp_postmeta` table, well at least it should be. Did you try specifying post type in your `get_pages` (`'post_type' => 'page'`)?

Comment: Yes sir. I'm making this theme from scratch... is there any action you have to do before the _wp_page_template appearing in that table? Because the option for the template appears perfectly and it remembers it everytime I edit the page.

Comment: @JuanBonnett well **make sure that SOME page has really assigned `page-gallery.php` as it's template** ... *Because if `_wp_page_template` is not even there, it would have to mean you did not assign that template anywhere :)*